# ちゃんと笑いの分かる君よりいいのがね

Tags: meaning

From Naruto ch. 603,

[image]

I am not sure about this part:「ちゃんと笑いの分かる君よりいいのがね」. Does 笑いの分かる君 mean "you who understands smiling"? It sounds odd to me. 君よりいいのが follows the next sentence, right? "What we are better than you is..."

Comment: 「笑いがわかる」の「笑い」は smiling じゃないです。「ジョークがわかる」「ユーモアがわかる」, understand jokes/humor って意味です

Comment: @Chocolate ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちゃんと笑いの分かる and 君よりいい both modify の, which I believe refers to 感情.

> ［［ちゃんと笑いの分かる］［君よりいい］の（＝感情）］が（ある）。

---

[Edit]

ちゃんと might be outside of the brackets modifying ある.

> ちゃんと［［笑いの分かる］［君よりいい］の（＝感情）］が（ある）。

Comment: 3コマ目の「君**の**は感情のない人造体！」の「の」は何でしょう？

Comment: @Chocolate - さぁ、「その訳分かんないの」ですかね。話を知らないので何とも言えません。

Comment: @Chocolate 「その訳分かんないの」は「魔像」と呼ばれる人造生命的な何かで、残りの2人は半分ではなく全部それで出来ているっぽいです。https://naruto-ag23.hatenadiary.org/entry/20121002/p1

Answer (score -1):

It means　There's nothing／no one better than you, who knows how to smile.
Hope it helps！